# How to obtain the currently selected View onKeyDown method?

Tags: android

I'm trying find if a specific View is selected following a key press. For this purpose I was trying to use the onKeyDown method on my main activity.

I already tried to set a setOnKeyListener on the fragment but it wasn't registering any input.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN) {
        // Check if it's selecting a specific View
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Any idea how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

one from many approach that may use, fun n silly maybe, but it was work for me

on Global declaration

```
Integer iLastView=0;
```

on View that selected before

```
iLastView=iView;
```

and last in the inKeyDown

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN) {
        if(iLastView==iView1){
               //something here
        }else if(check){.....}
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: I don't think this accomplishes what I'm looking for